# написал бот для парсинга строки на сайте , возникает проблема с последней строкой, не могу зацыклить код , не хочу чтобы бот ее отправлял снова

Tags: python, парсер, циклы

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="parser")
async def paser(message: types.Message):
    def create_browser(webdriver_path):
        browser_options = Options()
        browser_options.add_argument("--headless")
        browser_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, chrome_options=browser_options)
        print("скейт")
        return browser

        browser.get(url)
    url = "https://csfail.net/bonuses"
    browser = create_browser(f'C:/Users/labch/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
    while True:
        page_html = browser.page_source
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            await send_message(CHANNEL_ID,re.findall(r'promo__code"> (\S+) </div>', page_html)[0])
        except:
            pass
        try:
            await send_message(CHANNEL_ID,re.findall(r'promo__type"> (\S+) </div>', page_html)[0])
        except:
            pass
async def send_message(channel_id: int, text: str):
    await bot.send_message(channel_id, text)

 if name == "main":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Добавьте весь код

Comment: так, если вы не хотите что-бы бот отправлял строку еще раз, зачем вы взяли код в while True?

Comment: я бы, на вашем месте, взял бы код в функцию, а бесконечный цикл и так происходит в боте